# How can I stream simple text file using

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read a simple text file using reflection just as a learning case. I'm not getting an error, but I'm also not getting the desired result of "hello world". The variable stream is coming back null.

```
string output = "";
var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using (var stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream("ConsoleApp1.data1.txt"))
{
   if (stream != null)
   {
      var reader = new StreamReader(stream);
      output = reader.ReadToEnd();
      Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: If you right click on the file and choose Properties, did you set the Build Action to "Embedded Resource"?

Comment: Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream returns: The manifest resource; or null if no resources were specified during compilation or if the resource is not visible to the caller. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @BlackSpy, that worked, if you make that an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading from a manifest resource, which means the text file needs to be embedded in the dll. Right click on the file and choose Properties, then set the Build Action to "Embedded Resource".